# Can't perform arithmetics on table values

Tags: lua, lua-table

Why can't I perform a arithmetics on these table values? The keys of `index` are redirecting to numerical values:

```
for q = 1, 42 do
    horizontalwin = index [q] + index [q + 1] + index [q + 2] + index [q + 3]
    print (horizontalwin)
end
```

Comment: Define "can't". Print the value of each of those fields before that line. What error are you getting? "attempt to perform arithmetic on field '?' (a nil value)"?

Comment: When I print all keys and values of the table, everything seems to be fine. The error that I'm getting is exactly the error thay you're naming.

Comment: At some point it has to not be fine if that error happens. You need to find that case. But @PaulKulchenko is almost certainly correct about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running over the number of elements in the table; note that for using `q` through `q+3` keys, you need to have 45 elements in your table, not 42. If you only have 42 elements in the table, when `q` is 40, then `q+3` will try to retrieve `index[43]` value, which is `nil` and this triggers the error you see.

You either need to change the loop to go from 1 to 42-3 or change the sum to something like:

```
horizontalwin =
  index [q] + (index [q + 1] or 0) + (index [q + 2] or 0) + (index [q + 3] or 0)
```